# SAPUI5, Datasource from 2 different URL

Tags: odata, sapui5, datasource

I am new in SAPUI5, currently I am building a SAPUI5 application and consumes ODATA services from backend. When I am creating an application and select service URL.
Service URL as following attachment.

[image]

However, now in my application I have to add another data source with totally url. In my manifest.json. I just can change different navigation of the same url as following

```
"dataSources": {
        "mainService": {
            "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/SEPMRA_SHOP/",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0",
                "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
            }
        },
        "mainService2": {
            "uri": "/odata/V2/OData/OData.svc/",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0",
                "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
            }
        }
    },
```

How can I add different url of datasource for SAPUI5 application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a Destination in your SAP Cloud Platform cockpit.
You are already using one called "odata - odata" as per your screenshot.

You have the [documentation here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/1e110da0ddd8453aaf5aed2485d84f25.html)

And a screenshot below.

Fuertheremore, if you want to access a NW system in your private network from the cloud, you need to set up a Cloud connector. Check the [documentation here](https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/hcp-cloud-connector-setup.html)

#### SAP Cloud Platform configuration

[image]

Once you have your destinations configured and you dataSource block already there (as you have in the screenshot), you need to create 2 OData models. So in your metadata.json file, go to the bottom, and there is a node called 'models' where you probably have something like this:

```
    "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
               ...
            }
        },
        "": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
            "settings": {
                "defaultOperationMode": "Server",
                "defaultBindingMode": "OneWay",
                "defaultCountMode": "Request"
            },
            "dataSource": "mainService",
            "preload": true
        },
        "dataModel2": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
            "settings": {
                "defaultOperationMode": "Server",
                "defaultBindingMode": "OneWay",
                "defaultCountMode": "Request"
            },
            "dataSource": "mainService2",
            "preload": true
        }
    }
```

You need to add the block `"dataModel2":{ ... }`

Where:

- "dataModel2" is the name of your second model (choose the one you like, it doesn't need to be dataModel2).
- Make sure that `"dataSource": "mainService2"` so this model points to your second data source
- In the settings you can set the model as you want. Probably the most important is the "defaultBindingMode". Set it as "OneWay" if it is only readable, or "TwoWay" if it is read/write-able.

Then you just need to define all your bindings to this model with the modelName you choose as described in the first bullet point. For instance:

```
<Text text="{dataModel2>/path/to/my/property"}"></Text>
```

But be careful with this architecture, as per SAP Best Practices, you should try always to use only one OData service. Having more than one could be a nightmare to maintain, specially if you suscribe to model change/dataRequested/dataReceived events or for error handling with metadataFailed/metadataLoaded events, because you will have to manage them for both models and they are asynchronous...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But what I need to do is I need to access odata datasource and new datasource in one SAPUI5 application

Comment: Ok, I will guess you have the destinations configured properly. Then you need to add a second OData model consuming your second dataSource. I have edited my answer with more details

Comment: Noted. Thanks a lot